We're on a roll!
Preface
This'll be the last one I post for the day. This one has a little twist; for your answer to be accepted, you also need to figure out the connection between all sixteen of these words.
Good luck!
Wall











SPRINT
CAREER
PUSH
STRING


MANAGE
BOOTLEG
DIRECT
DEAL


RACE
TRAIN
PRESIDE
STRAIGHT


GOVERN
SEQUENCE
HURRY
SMUGGLE




ConnieMnemonic is a bloody great moniker.

@RobGrant Hah hah, thanks!

Once you know the overarching theme, the word that is the synonym for all sixteen words (as found by @marin-takanov):

 run

the groups are much easier to find:
First group:

 to move speedily (verb):
 SPRINT CAREER RACE HURRY

Second group:

 to trade something illegally (verb):
 PUSH BOOTLEG DEAL SMUGGLE

Third group:

 a succession (noun):
 STRING TRAIN STRAIGHT SEQUENCE

Fourth group:

 to rule (verb):
 MANAGE DIRECT PRESIDE GOVERN


Terrific! Well done :)

I think all these words are connected through various meanings and uses of the verb:

Run


SPRINT: To run at full speed over a short distance.
CAREER: As a verb, it means to move swiftly and in an uncontrolled way.
PUSH: To move forward by exerting force; informally, it can mean to run drugs (drug-running).
STRING: In programming, you can "run a string" of code or commands. Not 100% sure tho.
MANAGE: To run or oversee an operation or organization.
BOOTLEG: To illegally make, distribute, or sell goods related to "rum-running" during Prohibition.
DIRECT: To run or oversee a project, film, or performance.
DEAL: To distribute or sell, often used in contexts like "dealing cards" or "drug dealing" (again, running an operation). Not sure again here if this fits.
 RACE: To compete by running.
TRAIN: A mode of transportation that runs on tracks.
PRESIDE: To run a meeting or formal gathering.
STRAIGHT: In card games, a "straight" is a sequence or run of consecutive cards.
GOVERN: To run the affairs of a state or organization.
SEQUENCE: A continuous or connected series, similar to a run in patterns or numbers.
HURRY: To move quickly; to run.
SMUGGLE: To move goods illegally into or out of a country, akin to "smuggling" or "running" contraband.


You've absolutely got the overarching theme, well done! But there's still 4 categories to do; this is still a connect-wall :)

I din't knew I had to group them. I don't see this condition anywhere in your post.

Sorry dude. Standard rules for a connect-wall. The post stipulates an additional layer, not a replacement to the standard rules. Apologies if that was unclear!
